# Alternative to box-decoration-break

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass

Is there any alternative to box-decoration-break for IE?

My customer needs to have working solution for IE but IE does not support that.

```css
.class1 {
  display: inline;
  padding: 32px 20px 16px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -o-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.class2 {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 40;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="class1">
   <h1 class="class2">Lorem Ipsum Ipsum</h1>
</span>
```

Comment: Can you please add your relevant HTML to reproduce desired behaviour?

Comment: code added, thanks for notice me

Comment: To be honest I don't see any special effects using your code. Just white text on black background. Moved your HTML and CSS to code snippet, feel free to edit it.

Comment: For those wondering what in the world this does: [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break), [caniuse table](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-decoration-break)

Answer (score 3):

"Box-shadow" is a good alternative.

```
blockquote span {
   font-size: 1.4em;
   line-height: 1.8em;
   display: inline;
   color: #fff;
   background: blue;
   box-shadow: 6px 0 0 5px blue, -6px 0 0 5px blue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/xxKVKPo

Support is way better (IE 9).

Answer (score 0):

IE browsers not supporting box-decoration-break property. You need to use a polyfill.
Check this link, its a polyfill for box-decoration-break, it may help you.
https://github.com/entepe85/decofill

Comment: I've check decofill but It looks like it does not work for me, but I found nice quick solution for my problem, so still thanks for all you Guys ;)

Comment: Can you share that?